# Why is Jquery not being loaded correctly?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am so aggravated, and have spent hours trying to solve this compatibility issue. If anyone can help it would be very, very appreciated.

I am using [Jdock](http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/) to display a navigation at http://cailinshea.com/ - which works fine in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 - but does not work in IE8.

I would really like to avoid having to create a second navigation for IE8, is there some way to get my navigation to work in IE8?

Comment: What exactly does not work? In your title, you mention jQuery not being loaded. Do you know that for sure? Is it limited to IE8?

Comment: I believe the reason it is not working is due to jQuery not being loaded before my navigation script. I believe it is limited to IE8 - I have tested in Safari, Chrome, FF, and IE9 with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved this by doing CSS browser testing and loading different styles accordingly.